# JQuery 500 Error on file upload POST Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

I am trying to submit a file to a public API via AJAX. [Here](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/aimastering/aimastering/1.0.0) is the API I am working with, and we can assume it is working correctly as I'll explain in a moment.

Here is my HTML form and input:

```
<form id="innerFileSection" name="innerFileSection" >
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept=".wav,.mp3"/>
    <label id="labelForFileUpload" for="fileUpload">Upload File</label>
</form>
```

And my Javascript:

```
 var item = document.forms["innerFileSection"]["fileUpload"].files[0];
    var form = new FormData();
    console.log(item);
    form.append("file", item);
    $.ajax("https://aimastering.com:443/api/library_audios", {
      method: "POST",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + key,
        accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      data: {
        form
      }
    })
```

Here, "key" is a variable with my Bearer API Key.

I've tested this in Postman (API interface) and it returns successfully. Here is the AJAX automatically generated from Postman:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\sound.wav");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://aimastering.com:443/api/library_audios",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "9d3609f6-f495-4978-b53e-3e392ca914aa"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I am assuming I am getting a 500 error because the file I'm sending is not in the right format - but, I don't understand where I can go from here to format the file successfully.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not creating your formData object like this: `var form = new FormData(document.forms["innerFileSelection"])` and skipping the append?

Comment: Not particularly - after long periods of bug-fixing, I was trying whatever worked to get my code in the same format as the Postman request.

Comment: No clue and that API is poorly documented. So can't help.